# How to play audio file from raw/assets folder on the native/default media player?

Tags: android, mp3, media-player

I know i can play an mp3 file in the media player like that:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();  
intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);  
File file = new File(YOUR_SONG_URI);  
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "audio/*");  
startActivity(intent);
```

Following [this link](http://androidbook.blogspot.co.uk/2009/08/referring-to-android-resources-using.html) I tried to get the URI like:

```
Uri audio = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.audio.test/"+R.raw.audio1);
Log.d(TAG,"uri:"+audio.toString());
```

and

```
Uri audio = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.audio.test/raw/audio");
Log.d(TAG,"uri:"+audio.toString());
```

Which outputs the expected result:

```
01-24 15:28:23.190: D/MyClass(30234): uri:android.resource://com.audio.test/2131034112
01-24 15:29:13.: D/MyClass(30234): uri:android.resource://com.audio.test/raw/audio1
```

But it doesn't work. The media player does not start. Any ideas why?

**Update**

I included a createChooser and instead of the expected list with players i get a "Unable to find application to perform this action" message. This is my exact code:

```
 public void playAudio(){
          Intent viewMediaIntent = new Intent();   
          viewMediaIntent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);        
          Uri audio = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.audio.test/raw/"+R.raw.audio1);       
          Log.d(TAG,"uri:"+audio.toString());
          viewMediaIntent.setDataAndType(audio, "video/*");   
          viewMediaIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
          Log.d(TAG,"Starting");
          Intent i = Intent.createChooser(viewMediaIntent, "Play Music");
            mGap.startActivity(i);
          Log.d(TAG,"Started");
      }
```

**Update 2**

Thank you @CommonsWare for the explanation. Now I understand why it doesn't work. But the problem remains, can I achieve what I want? Get a Uri of a file stored in the raw/assets folder with a file:// scheme?

**Update 3**

I found a way to do it, although it's not the best it works. I have only 3 files and this doesn't delay the execution at all. I am copying the file from the res/raw to a local directory on the phone and getting the Uri from that file. Any suggestions on how to avoid that step are appreciated.

```
 public void copyFileToDir(String audioFile){
          File test = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC + "/" + audioFile + ".mp3");
          if (test.exists()){
              Toast.makeText(mGap, "Exists", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              return;
          }
          File dest = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC);
          int i = mGap.getResources().getIdentifier("raw/"+audioFile, "string", mGap.getPackageName());
          InputStream in = mGap.getResources().openRawResource(i);
          // Used the File-constructor
          OutputStream out;
        try {
            out = new FileOutputStream(new File(dest, audioFile + ".mp3"));
              // Transfer bytes from in to out
              byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
              int len;
              try {
                  // A little more explicit
                  while ( (len = in.read(buf, 0, buf.length)) != -1){
                       out.write(buf, 0, len);
                  }
              } finally {
                  // Ensure the Streams are closed:
                  in.close();
                  out.close();
              }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 


      }


      public void playAudio(String audioFile){
          copyFileToDir(audioFile);
          File dest = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC + "/" + audioFile + ".mp3");
          Uri r = Uri.fromFile(dest);         
          Intent viewMediaIntent = new Intent();   
          viewMediaIntent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);                                 
          viewMediaIntent.setDataAndType(r, "audio/*");   
          viewMediaIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);          
          Intent i = Intent.createChooser(viewMediaIntent, "Play Music");
            mGap.startActivity(i);

      }

      public void playVideo(String movieurl){
          Intent intentToPlayVideo = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
          intentToPlayVideo.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(movieurl), "video/*");
          Log.d(TAG,"Playing:" + movieurl);
          mGap.startActivity(intentToPlayVideo);
      }
```

Comment: But there are no subfolders! res/raw/audio.mp3.

Comment: What makes you think that there is an app on your device that supports the `android.resource` scheme?

Comment: @CommonsWare Sorry I'm not really sure what that means. The whole android.resource thing was copy paste from the blog.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `startActivity()`, you are trying to start an activity. The `Intent` you pass to `startActivity()` indicates what activity -- or selection out of a set of available activities -- you want to start. In your case, you are trying to view an `android.resource://` `Uri`. This is not an `http://` `Uri`, nor an `https://` `Uri`, nor a `file://` `Uri`.

Activities that advertise themselves as supporting operations like this have, in their `<intent-filter>` a statement of what `Uri` schemes they support. You are assuming that there is an app, on the user's device, that supports an `android.resource://` scheme. Personally, I do not think that this is a safe assumption.
`http://`, `https://`, and `file://` should be safe, and `content://` (for a `ContentProvider`) is fairly likely as well.

For example, the AOSP Music app does not support the `android.resource` scheme, based on [its current manifest contents](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_music/blob/master/AndroidManifest.xml).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! Even if i can't do it now at least I understand why!

Answer (score 4):

Any reason why don't you use the MediaPlayer directly? You can pass the resource id directly

```
int resourceId = R.raw.your_media_resource;
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create( context, resourceId );
mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener( new OnCompletionListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onCompletion( MediaPlayer mp )
    {
        mp.release();
    }
} );
mediaPlayer.start();
```

Comment: Yes, i don't want to create a UI. I want to play it on whatever media player the user is already using!

Answer (score 0):

<del>It is not possible to use content from your RES folder outside of the App. The content is inside the App and not reachable from outside the App. If you want to make the content available you have to implement your own ContentProvider returning the data.</del>

@CommonsWare is right. See http://iserveandroid.blogspot.nl/2011/01/how-to-access-resources-from-other.html

Comment: Actually, resources are world-readable, and therefore can be reached by third-party apps.

Comment: As far as i know you can read resources from other apps. I'm just not sure on how to do it!

Comment: @CommonsWare: Thats new to me. Could you please give an example? Do you have to provide special permissions? Can i access all resources from all applications?

Comment: @user1433372: "Could you please give an example? " -- see `createPackageContext()`. "Do you have to provide special permissions?" -- no. "Can i access all resources from all applications?" -- AFAIK, there are no limits.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to set the sound URI on the [Notification.Builder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html), use

```
 Uri.parse("android.resource://com.my.great.application/"
                        + R.raw.mysound);
```

where `R.raw.mysound` can be something like `mysoud.ogg` in the raw resources folder.

However I am not sure if MP3 is exactly supported. As these are just internal resources of your application, try to convert to OGG.

Comment: I don't get it. How exactly is that any different from what i'm trying?

Comment: I know it works, I have tested two minutes ago. The only reason then could be Android device does not support MP3.

Comment: Sorry but that still doesn't show me what is different on your code and on mine. Can you please include a larger block of code? How did you make it work?

Comment: I say, try to convert to OGG with something like http://audio.online-convert.com/convert-to-ogg. It is not visible in the code as the file extension is not part of R.raw.resourcename.