# Android raw resource file not readable

Tags: android, file-permissions, android-2.2-froyo

I have got several mp3 files added as raw resource to my project. I would like to play them with AudioPlayer. I had FileNotfoundException and I backtraced it to find that the files can be found but they are not readable:
        mp1.stop();
        mp1.reset();

```
    playedSound = R.raw.sip02;
    String str = getResources().getString(playedSound);
    File file = new File(str);
    //((File)file).setReadable(true);
    boolean readable = file.canRead();      //returns TRUE
    file.setReadOnly();
    readable = file.canRead();              //returns TRUE
    FileInputStream inputStream = null;
                try {
        inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();                 //enters this branch
        }
```

I cannot call file.setReadable() because I use API level 7.

My manifest:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       package="com.example.movingcircle"
       android:versionCode="1"
       android:versionName="1.0" >

       <uses-sdk
           android:minSdkVersion="8"
           android:targetSdkVersion="8" />

       <application
           android:allowBackup="true"
           android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
           android:label="@string/app_name"
           android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
           <activity
               android:name="com.example.movingcircle.MovingCircle"
               android:label="@string/app_name" >
               <intent-filter>
                   <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                   <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
               </intent-filter>
           </activity>
       </application>

   </manifest>
```

Comment: you want to play mp3??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14505153/how-to-play-audio-file-from-raw-assets-folder-on-the-native-default-media-player

Comment: I think the problem is not with the mp3 playing. I was able to play mp3 with this code in another app. In this particular situation I found that the mp3 is not readable.

Comment: `getResources().getString(playedSound);` returns a String from strings.xml, not a path to a file from raw

Comment: No, it does not. It returns "res/raw/sip02.mp3"

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
  MediaPlayer mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(PlayWorld.this, R.raw.your_mp3);
```

Comment: I already created the mediaplayer formerly. Actualy I want it to play a different sound than It was playing before. I would presume that you can call mPlayer.create() only once.

Comment: @user1105818 http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html