# how can i play a mp3 file from raw in a simple player in android?

Tags: android, playback

how can I play a mp3 file from Resources/raw in a simple player in android ? like in file preview in default file manger in android

please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) like this (called inside an Activity):

```
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.mp3file);
mp.start();
```

Comment: i want to play with a simple player with progressBar and a play/stop button

Comment: With the MediaPlayer class you have all the methods needed to do that. Use `getDuration()` to know the max value of the ProgressBar.  With `getCurrentPosition()` you will know what's the value to put on the ProgressBar. Then you link your play and stop buttons to `start()` and `stop()`.

Comment: is it possible to use intent and play with default player in android?

Comment: Sure it is. Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14505153/how-to-play-audio-file-from-raw-assets-folder-on-the-native-default-media-player

Comment: thanks i try that but i want to play the sound in a player like when we preview an Audio file in sd card ok?

Comment: I'm not sure about that behaviour. That depends completely on the file manager you're using. Maybe someone else will come in and help you more.